# Oracle SQL - have 2 tables and want to find the ship from and delivery to codes from 2nd table based on ID values from first table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 tables.

Table A has item code, org_id for ship from, org_id for deliver to

Table B has org_id mapped to org_code

I want to do something like:

```
select a.item_code, b.org_code AS "ship from", b.org_code as "deliver to"
from table a, table b
where a.org_id = b.org_id
```

Can someone please help me out?  How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two joins:

```
select a.item_code, bs.org_code AS "ship from", bt.org_code as "deliver to"
from a left join
     b bs
     on a.ship_from = bs.org_id left join
     b bt
     on a.ship_to = bt.org_id;
```

This uses `left join` in case some of the values are `NULL` or have no matching values.

Comment: Thanks  a lot.  This really helped.  I will need to read up on joins and such.  Thank you